# How to undo a deleted folder in a git commit

Tags: git, git-commit

I have a git branch that contains many needed changes.  It also appears that a big folder was accidentally deleted and committed to the same branch at the same time.

Is there a way to tell git to ignore the changes to the deleted folder that already were commited (within the branch, not merged yet) while keeping the other changes?

Comment: Interactive rebase might help you.

Comment: I would do a `git checkout HEAD~1 path/to/folder/*`

Comment: When I try that, I get this message: error: pathspec 'HEAD-1' did not match any file(s) known to git.

Comment: @Erich Is there a copy of the folder in your `master` branch?

Answer (score 0):

Try this awesome command -

```
git fetch

// Make sure you can see the deleted directory

git ls-tree -r COMMIT_ID

git checkout COMMIT_ID -- path/to/deleted/folder
```